# How to write real value of -2.12683575e-04 in a file (Python)

Tags: python

I am currently working with really tiny values and when I try to write a value like **-0.000212683575** in a file, it write me **-2.12683575e-04**.
The problem is that I would like to have this value **-0.000212683575** written in the file or a least this one **-0.00021268** if there are too much numbers.

How could I do this ?

**I use Python 2.7**

Thank you very much

Comment: What've you tried thus far? Also, what do you mean by 'real value'?

Comment: `-2.000012683575  != -2.12683575e-04` !

Comment: What I mean by real value is to write **-0.00021268357** instead of **-2.12683575e-04** in a file.
If I try something like `file.write(str(number))` , it will write in my file **-2.12683575e-04**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python allows you to choose formats.  For example, this gives the scientific notation that you don't want:

```
>>> x =  -0.00021268357
>>> '{:.2e}'.format(x)
'-2.13e-04'
```

But, this format gives the decimal notation that you prefer:

```
>>> '{:.9f}'.format(x)
'-0.000212684'
```

We can use these formats when we write to a file:

```
>>> with open('output', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('{:.9f}'.format(x))
... 
>>> open('output').read()
'-0.000212684'
```

You can read about the `format` method, and all its complex and powerful features, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting).

Python also offers `printf` style formatting.  For example:

```
>>> '%f' % x
'-0.000213'
>>> '%e' % x
'-2.126836e-04'
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing a number in a file, you can write it as a string and it'll be all you need. ex:

```
>>> num = -0.000212683575
>>> f = open("a.txt","w")
>>> f.write(str(num))
>>> f.close()
>>> open("a.txt","r").read()
'-0.000212683575'
>>>
```

Comment: I tried but in my case that didn't work. But John1024 solution worked !
By the way, thank you for your help