# Group by Age against average Salary

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a tableA like

```
| ID | name | Age | Salary | Sex

  2  |  Tom | 20  | 30000   | 1
  3  |  Ken | 25  | 40000  | 2
  5  |  Gen | 50  | 80000   | 2
  6  |  Per | 20  | 60000   | 1
```

Pre information: I have check my columns of ID, Age, Sex are int64 data type, but Salary data type is float.

I want to calculate average salary agains age.

My code is

```
tableA.groupby(['Age']).mean()
```

The result comes out

```
      | ID  |  Sex
Age
  20  |  4  |   1
  25  |  3  |   2
  50  |  5  |   2
```

Then I realise my salary data type is float not int64, so the Salary mean is not show, so I convert it to int65 by

```
tableA['Salary'] = tableA['Salary'].astype(np.int64)

#But I got warning:A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
#Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I keep group by and calculate average salary against age
by

```
tableA.groupby(['Age'])['Salary'].mean()
```

```
      | 
Age
  20  |  4.500000e+04
  25  |  6.000000e+04
  50  |  8.000000e+04
```

My expected result is

```
      |   Salary
Age
  20  |  45000
  25  |  60000
  50  |  80000
```

I have convert the Salary type to int64 by why still got the data look like float? How to get the expected result with Salary column name (As I need to create a graph later )?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to help. I would suggest two things.

One: Changing the type after the operation.

```
table = df.groupby(['Age'])['Salary'].mean().astype(int) #this should work
```

Two: Changing the type to float instead of numpy's int64.

```
tableA['Salary'] = tableA['Salary'].astype(float)
table = df.groupby(['Age'])['Salary'].mean()
```

Please tell me if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change scientific notation to decimal notation.

Check here:

[How to write real value of -2.12683575e-04 in a file (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319104/how-to-write-real-value-of-2-12683575e-04-in-a-file-python)